# Encode user input to match encoded data frame

Tags: label-encoding

I am trying to encode a user's input to match the encoded dataframe i have created beforehand. However, i am unsure on how to do so.

dataframe with the label encoded columns:

```
cdata =pd.DataFrame({'ServiceItemName':ServiceItemName, 'OpticalDiagnosisCode':OpticalDiagnosisCode, 'Frequency': Frequency, 'Description': Description})
```

cdata

[Image of cdata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFNBz.png)

example of user input (ServiceItemName, Frequency, and Description)

```
test_input1 = ['SYSTANE ULTRA', '4 HOURLY / BOTH EYES', 'LE']
```